# Printer settings not working for a user

Tags: printing

I have been fooling around with printer settings trying to do something clever. Not sure what I did, the result is that some time later it turned out that I cannot configure printing any more.

- no printers shown when a print dialog is started from evince or other apps
- when opening printer settings, first there is a waiting sign for some time, and then I get the error  "the system printing service doesn't seem to be available".
- if starting `system-config-printer` from command line, I get "Failed to connect to server".
- there is no entry in `/var/log/cups/access_log` or `error_log`
- cups of course installed

However, when I set up a new user, that user can add and configure printers without any issues, printing works without any problems, `system-config-printer` starts without any issues and allows adding printers. Therefore, this is not a system-wide problem, just the problem of my user. However, I have not a single clue where to look for it.  Any ideas what I could do and how?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in incorrect user configuration of cups. Somehow I ended up with a file called `client.conf` in the `~/.cups` directory with the incorrect cups server IP. Removing the directory and restarting cups with `sudo systemctl restart cups` worked.